# Fetching the changes from my colleague's git branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

I want get the changes from my collegue's git branch. His changes are in his branch 'teamBranch'. I added his repo and fetched it with below commands.

> git remote add team 'his repo with URL'
>
> git fetch team

I am able to get his repo listing with

> git remote -v

But my problem is, I am not able to see the branch 'teamBranch' with the command

> git branch -r

I can only see his master branch not teamBranch. Can anyone please help me ?
Thank you all !

Comment: You have created the remote name, and fetched the remote's branches so their refs are in a spearate name space to your local branches. You now have to create a local branch with the name you want to call it, such as 'collegueJoesBranch' (e.g. if Fred also has another teamBranch it would clash). Try `git checkout -t -b collegueJoesBranch team/teamBranch` (and don't forget to checkout the man pages ;-)

Comment: It is giving error when i do this:
fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches.
Did you intend to checkout 'team/teamBranch' which can not be resolved as commit?

Comment: What version of git are you using? You may not have fetched all the branches. Or the capitalisation may not be correct.

Comment: i am using git version 1.7.12
How to fetch all the branches.. I used command "git fetch" for this. Is there any other command to fetch with branch level ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

first type 'git branch -a' to get full list of branches
if you don't see it do 'git fetch' again.

once you see it in the list try to pull it implicitly : 'git checkout teamBranch'.
This command will checkout the branch from remote unless you have it already locally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I am not able to see the branch teamBranch even after fetching it multiple times.